# Flutter Dart - Connect API to UI using Getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am flutter beginner.
I'm trying to connect the API to the UI using GetX, I got an error on the API service class.

Error line:
static Future fetchProducts() async

Error in **fetch Products()**:
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr', is a potentially non-nullable type.

Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance!

API Code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:practice/productmodule/models/product_model.dart';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';

    class ApiService {
    static var client = http.Client();
     static Future<ProductModel> fetchProducts() async {
    var response =
        await client.get(Uri.parse('https://....../1'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;
      return productModelFromJson(jsonString);
    }}
    }
```

Comment: Use `FutureBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only returning the response inside the `if` block. Consider throwing an `Exception` or returning an error response in JSON format like so:

```
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:practice/productmodule/models/product_model.dart';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';

    class ApiService {
    static var client = http.Client();
     static Future<ProductModel> fetchProducts() async {
    var response =
        await client.get(Uri.parse('https://....../1'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;
      return productModelFromJson(jsonString);
      }else{
       return ({'error':'Please try again later.'});
        }
     }
    }
```